# On the canonical neighborhoods

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, manifolds, ricci-flow

Suppose $M$ is a 3-dimensional manifold, John W. Morgan and Frederick Tsz-Ho Fong in their "Ricci Flow
and Geometrization
of 3-Manifolds" book as a definition of canonical neighborhoods have written:

> We fix an $\epsilon >0$, there are essentially $3$ types of $\epsilon$-canonical neighborhoods:
>
> (1) ($\epsilon$-neck) - a neighborhood $N_{\epsilon}\subset M$ diffeomorphic to $S^2\times (-\epsilon ^{-1},\epsilon ^{-1})$ under diffeomorphism $\varphi:S^2\times (-\epsilon ^{-1},\epsilon ^{-1})\to N_\epsilon$, such that the rescaled pull-back metric $R(x,t)\varphi ^*g(t)$ on $S^2\times (-\epsilon ^{-1},\epsilon ^{-1})$ is within $\epsilon$ in $C^{[\epsilon^{-1}]}$-topology to the product of the round metric on $S^2$ with $R=1$ with the usual metric on $(-\epsilon ^{-1},\epsilon ^{-1})$.
>
> (2) ($\epsilon$-cap) - topologically $B^3$ or a punctured real projective $3$-space $\mathbb{R}P^3_0$ and whose end is a $\epsilon$-neck.
>
> (3) connected component of positive sectional curvature.
>
> A point $x\in M$ is said to **have an $\epsilon$-canonical neighborhood** if it lies in the
> central two-sphere of an $\epsilon$-neck, lies in an $\epsilon$-cap in the complement of the $\epsilon$-neck
> forming the end of the cap, or lies in a component of positive sectional curvature.

**Question 1:** What is the meaning of "*within $\epsilon$ in $C^{[\epsilon^{-1}]}$-topology*"?

**Question 2:** Why do we consider **rescaled** pull-back metric $R(x,t)\varphi ^*g(t)$? What is necessity of this action? In other words if we have just considered pull-back metric $\varphi ^*g(t)$, what would be wrong then?

**Question 3:** Is the boundary of the punctured real projective $3$-space ,$\mathbb{R}P^3_0$, $S^2$?

**Question 4:** I can visualize $\epsilon$-neck and $\epsilon$-cap. These types of canonical neighborhoods have shapes like following figures. Now, what is visualization of type (3) of the definition of the canonical neighborhoods? Essentially, what is "*a component of positive sectional curvature*" ?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I ask this question also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457124/on-the-canonical-neighborhoods) but nobody answer to me and the number of views is only 15. I need the answer. Excuse me for crossposting.

Comment: This material has been treated in various places. Have you tried having a look at Kleiner and Lott notes, Besson Bessieres Maillot and Porti's book, or Terence Tao's Blog ? Maybe you'll find explanation that suit you better there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to question (1): the notation means that if you let $k$ be the greatest integer not larger than $\varepsilon^{-1}$, you want the covariant derivatives  of the rescaled pullback metric of order up to and including $k$ to be all of size smaller than $\varepsilon$ in the product metric.

Answer to question (3): yes. If you puncture any compact 3-manifold, then near the puncture it looks like a punctured $\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e. $S^2 \times \mathbb{R}$.

Answer to question (4): a component of positive sectional curvature looks like a sphere, or a finite quotient of a sphere (a lens space or 3-dimensional real projective space).